# <initializer_list> with references to functions

Tags: c++, initializer-list

i would like to ask if there is any chance to fill up the `<initializer_list>` with references to functions. Let's say i have function:

```
double refce( double (&f1)(double), double in ){
    return f1(in);
}
```

and instead of calling it like:

```
double a[3];

a[0] = refce( sin, 3.1415);
a[1] = refce( cos, 3.1415);
a[2] = refce( tan, 3.1415);
```

is it possible to write function that will work like this:

```
double a*;
a = refce_list( {sin, cos, tan}, 3.1415);
```

I have tried to use initializer list, but apparently i don't know ho to paste the type to the list. Also i tried #include "cstdarg" style but i could not figure out the proper syntax. Is it even possible?

Thanks 
Buddy

Comment: Don't use references, use pointers.

Comment: Can i ask why i should prefer pointer before references? Because in the reference case no one can throw nullptr in it.

Comment: Because you cannot have an initializer list of references...

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <initializer_list>

void refce(std::initializer_list<double (*)(double)> il, double in)
{
    for (auto* f : il)
    {
        f(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you add the * to the type in the range for loop? It's not needed. I'd expect to have a pointer to function pointer now, but it works like this. It works without indirection too. Why is that the case?

Comment: @lars: Never hide qualifiers in aliases, generally. It's just poor style.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the function name from that poitner?

Comment: @Buddy: No more than you can obtain a variable name from an object pointer. (I.e. if you can enumerate all variables in your program, you could compare the pointer with all known addresses.)